# How to get female crew I failed to claim

Tags: world-of-tanks

I recently completed a mission which offered a female crew as a reward, and the popup came up to recruit, or cancel. I was doing something else so I cancelled, expecting to be able to recruit her later (and take my time deciding which nation etc.).

Now I can't find out how to go and recruit her. WoT forums have been no help. What's the process for claiming her?

Comment: I had a female crew I never assigned then lost. For a while when I logged in I would receive a prompt in the lower right corner, but then it disappeared after a few weeks. WoT support said this: "The Female crew that you are referring to that you were unable to assign in any tank is a compensation for the Campaign Mission that happens to have an issue before. Upon the release of the 9.21 Update on December 13th, the offer to recruit the free female crew member has now expired."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Enter the Campaign screen (below the "Battle!" button).
2. Pick the campaign in which you earned the female crew member.
3. Click the portrait of female crew member at the bottom of the screen (marked in red on the screenshot below).

[image]